# Best way to split a list of dictionaries?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have populated dictionaries which look like what's shown below
(values in below example is just to show the list that I get):

```
{'name': 'name1'},
{'col': 'somename', 'col2': 12344},
{'col': 'somename', 'col2': 12344},
{'col': 'somename', 'col2': 12344},
{'name': 'name2'},
{'col': 'somename', 'col2': 12344},
{'name': 'name2'},
{'col': 'somename', 'col2': 12344},
{'col': 'somename', 'col2': 12344},
{'col': 'somename', 'col2': 12344},
{'col': 'somename', 'col2': 12344},
{'col': 'somename', 'col2': 12344},
{'col': 'somename', 'col2': 12344}
```

and now I would like to split it into multiple lists/dicts. I want to split it by 'name' key. I have no idea how to do it in the best way.

One solution that came to my mind is to iterate through the elements and when I spot the 'name' put it into new list/dict.

Comment: So did you try implementing that solution? What happened?

Comment: is the order important to you? Python dicts are unordered (in fact since python 3.3 hashes are randomised for security reasons), so the order of the keys will not remain the same in different runs of your application. You might want to use a different structure.

Answer (score 2):

You can use list comprehension here.
Let have input list as `input_list`

```
list1 = [x for x in input_list if 'name' in input_list]
list2 = [x for x in input_list if 'col' in input_list]
```

Comment: this will not work if input is dict